# Could not find toolchain file: $ANDTOOLCHAIN while compiling assimp android

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I Could not find the toolchain file: `$ANDTOOLCHAIN` while compiling assimp android.

```
Error:
PS E:\assimp-master> cd buildandroid
PS E:\assimp-master\buildandroid> cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDTOOLCHAIN -DENABLE_BOOST_WORKAROUND=ON -DCMAKE_INSTAL
L_PREFIX=/assimp-2.0 -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a _DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-8 -DANDROID_FORCE_ARM_BUILD=TRUE ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:100 (message):
  Could not find toolchain file: $ANDTOOLCHAIN
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:39 (PROJECT)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (PROJECT):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe
```

to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.168+ga8fba1ebd7 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 07-09-2018 11:08:04.
Project "E:\assimp-master\buildandroid\CMakeFiles\3.12.1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [E:\assimp-master\buildandroid\CMakeFiles\3.12.1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "E:\assimp-master\buildandroid\CMakeFiles\3.12.1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"E:\assimp-master\buildandroid\CMakeFiles\3.12.1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(_CheckWindowsSDKInstalled target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets(46,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [E:\assimp-master\buildandroid\CMakeFiles\3.12.1\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.38
```

Exit code: 1

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDTOOLCHAIN` - I guess, instead of `$ANDTOOLCHAIN` should be actual path to Android toolchain.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Tsyvarev but i don't know the path of Android tool chain and could you tell me is that will be created automatically or need to create manual